# Swapping Elements Between Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a card game using Python. I've represented my cards as `5D`, `10H`, etc. So far I've used a `.pop()` approach to take cards from a deck [list] to the player's hand [list]. This was working great, until I created another list to act as the discard pile. When a player drops a card, I pop it into the discard list but it splits the characters into separate elements. No other list has done this throughout the program.

Example of what happens:

```
discard = []
hand = ['12D', '5C', '3D']
discard += hand.pop(0)
discard = ['1', '2', 'D']
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You might note that **discard** is one of those useful sequence methods.  Thus, consider getting a unique name for your personal list, such as **discard_stack**.

Comment: Yes the example isn't what I actually used it was just to show the problem. Thanks anyway! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` adds a sequence to a list and is an alias for `list.extend()`. You want to add an individual element to the list, so `+=` is not the correct operation for you.

Try this:

```
discard.append(hand.pop(0))
```

The Python documentation has [a convenient table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) that explains all of the operations on lists and other mutable sequence types.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much indeed! Works a treat.